# Is believing in God for salvation the same as believing in Jesus as Christ?

Tags: nature-of-god, soteriology, trinity, faith

I'm interested in answers particularly from Evangelicals who might disagree with this idea, as well as those who agree with it. I'm especially interested in theological considerations — i.e. does this misunderstand the Trinity.

Essentially the thought came to me, **if the Son is fully God, do those who have *never heard*** the Jewish name of the Messiah (Joshua, meaning the Lord saves) or the exact details of his virgin birth, death, and resurrection, **nevertheless believe in him** (for salvation) **when they trust in 'God' to forgive/save them?** This excludes those who reject Christ explicitly (ie. orthodox Islam).

This would not be a universalist position, but a form of inclusivism. More like a psychological/conceptual faith in the Messiah/Christ/Savior. I'm looking for arguments for/against, as well as relevant verses/examples/doctrines. A similar question was asked [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/77424/why-do-many-christians-talk-about-believing-in-jesus-rather-than-believing-in), but this gives it a trinitarian/soteriological bent.

For a practical consideration, Don Richardson (*Eternity in their Hearts*) notes a number of peoples geographically and intellectually isolated from Christianity/Judaism for centuries that had an underlying monotheism, and belief that this 'creator' was going to set things right if they only waited for special messengers bringing a special 'book'. Would their 'waiting for salvation' be comparable to some in Israel during the intertestamental period, waiting for the Messiah?

Comment: I have voted to close this as I consider it to be a matter of opinion. I know what I know because of up-bringing, country of origin, reading, conversation, tutorage and (above all) to the Providence of God which ensured that the gospel came to me. Then I know more because I sought more. (To him that hath shall be given.) The spiritual state of others is not my business and God will judge of all these kinds of matters in the day of judgment. Meanwhile, I testify when and where I can. (Like on here, for example.) The rest is just opinion.

Comment: @NigelJ I appreciate your perspective on the issue, I think some sort of hopeful agnosticism is a legitimate perspective on this point, but I'm looking for some people's Spirit led bible-study influenced perspectives. Evangelicals make some pretty clear statements depending on the denomination and I'm wondering what other denominations might say, see, page 238 here for example: https://cdn.cmalliance.org/wordpress/cmalliance/2021-CMA-Manual-English-7-29-21.pdf

Comment: Thanks @GratefulDisciple, your answer covers a lot of points, I'm particularly interested in a trinitarian evaluation, does it confuse the persons? Perhaps this is too nuanced a question about too deep a theological mystery, just wondering if others have more knowledge than I.

Comment: Some interesting insights in this question/answers:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/49022/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-athanasian-creeds-statement-that-believing-i